# Which preposition should be used in this case?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, adverbs

A person is holding sand in his hand and it starts to fall from it.
Is the sand:

1. leaking **through** his hand?
2. leaking **from** his hand?

Which would be correct? If none, which preposition should be used instead?

Comment: Pseudo-liquids like sand can ***dribble, drip, leak,...*** but we're probably more likely tto say ***through his fingers*** rather than ***from his hand[s]***. And the first verb you used to describe the situation is fine - *The sand **fell** [from his hand / through his fingers]*. Anything more is Off Topic writing advice.

Comment: Trickling or slipping.

Comment: @EdgarAllanPro I've edited your question and replaced *verb* with *preposition.* I presume that's what you wanted to know— which is the right preposition there, because you'd highlighted the prepositions in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify the aperture or orifice  through which leaking  takes place, the preposition is *through.*

*Fumes leaked **through** the crack in the pipe.*

*Water was leaking **through** a hole in the roof.*

On the other hand if it's the agent or medium you're interested in, the preposition is *from.*

*The gas had apparently leaked **from** a cylinder.*

In the case of hand, both prepositions would work. *leaking through the hand* implies the sand is leaking between the fingers, whereas *leaking from the hand* implies the sand is being transferred from the hand (perhaps to the ground below.)